# How to do such gradient block with shadow on css?

Tags: html, css

Here is a link on [image](http://i61.tinypic.com/4rum4h.png)

```
color: rgb(81, 134, 172);
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
vertical-align: super;
border-top: 2px solid rgb(81, 134, 172);
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(81, 134, 172);
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 11px 3px rgb(86, 141, 180);
```

is it possible on css?

Comment: Please create a Fiddle

Comment: Check [HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and play some.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/undrooleek/Th35f/2/ here is jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XKBkQ/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>User Options</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    content: "";
    height: 4px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}


.box:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    content: "";
    height: 4px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    max-width: 440px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Original Demo](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/details/aylso)**